# expdb seems successfully, but could not find dmp file on the output directory?

Tags: oracle11g

```
expdp dpuser/***@db directory=test_path schemas=test reuse_dumpfiles=y dumpfile=exp_1.dmp logfile=exp_1.log flashback_time=systimestamp

. . exported "TEST"."TMP_RMS_PRD_REFERENCES"                 1 KB       1 rows
. . exported "TEST"."_MDIR_DATABASE_VERSION"                 0 KB       0 rows
Master table "DPUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_08" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for DPUSER.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_08 is:
  /u03/folder1/exp_1.dmp
Job "DPUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_08" successfully completed at 13:24:02
```

export job works before I restart the Linux server, then this export job was failed (from console it did not tell the error message, job seems running ok,  but I could NOT find the dmp file), but I could not find any clues, does this relate oracle user permission or folder ?

```
SQL>select * from all_directories where directory_name='test_path';
/u03/folder1/

SQL>GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY test_path TO dpuser;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Data pump tells that everything is ok. You should find the output file "/u03/folder1/exp_1.dmp". Have you some post processing command that moves / removes the file after expdp? Is there some useful info in log file "/u03/folder1/exp_1.log"?

Comment: thanks, no any post processing command after expdb, I just run expdb command only, I check file system (df -h), the available space did not decrease, the dmp file was not created, but expdb command did not tell the reason -(Job "DPUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_08" successfully completed at 13:24:02)